# How to switch to frame source in selenium

Tags: python, html, forms, selenium, iframe

I want to click an frame source's radio button, but it doesn't work. I think, frame source doesn't have iframe id or name.
my code is this.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
Url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIStvhR347g'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://video-download.online')
driver.find_element_by_id("link").send_keys(Url)
driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
time.sleep(5)

#this part is problems... don't working
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe'))
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='radio']")[0].click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[contains(text(),'Proceed')]").click()
```

html source is this.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

...

<script>
        if (top.location !== location) {
            top.location = self.location;
        }
        if (location.host !== 'video-download.online' && location.host !== 'beta.video-download.online') {
            eval("location.href=''+'//'+'video-download.online';");
        }
    </script>
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="author" content="Luca Steeb"/>
<meta name="theme-color" content="#008679"/>
<meta name="description" content="Download from this uploaded.net premium link generator with highspeed. For free."/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Video-Download.online"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Download videos, mp3s and playlists from 1979 sites - for free."/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="video-download.online"/>
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="1143492155680932"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="//video-download.online/img/logo.jpg"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?1"/>
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="/img/logo_small.jpg"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/img/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Video-Download.online" href="/opensearch.xml"/>
<title>
Online Video Download
</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bt.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
<noscript><iframe height=0 src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TWMNRP"style=display:none;visibility:hidden width=0></iframe></noscript><script>!function(e,t,a,n,r){e[n]=e[n]||[],e[n].push({"gtm.start":(new Date).getTime(),event:"gtm.js"});var g=t.getElementsByTagName(a)[0],m=t.createElement(a),s="dataLayer"!=n?"&l="+n:"";m.async=!0,m.src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id="+r+s,g.parentNode.insertBefore(m,g)}(window,document,"script","dataLayer","GTM-TWMNRP")</script>

    <script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create','UA-54289597-5','auto');ga('send','pageview');</script>




    <script>function send(action) { ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'download-' + action) }</script>
    <script async src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>function _(n,i){i?window[n]?i():setTimeout(function(){_(n,i)},100):window.jQuery?window.jQuery(document).ready(function(){n(window.jQuery)}):setTimeout(function(){_(n)},100)}</script>
</head>

<body>

    <header class="navbar navbar-info navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle no-waves" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="nav-brand">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                        <img class="logo" src="/img/logo.svg" alt=""/>

                        <div class="parent">

                                Video-Download<small>.online</small>
                                <br/>
                                <span class="small-text">1979 sites officially supported</span>

                            <span id="changelog"></span>
                        </div>

                        <span class="clear"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <div class="social">
                    <div class="fb-like fb-nav" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/VideoDownload.online"
                         data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="social-close" title="Hide all social buttons">&times;</div>



                <li class=" ">
<a href="/">
    Home
</a>
</li>
                <li class=" ">
<a href="/sites">
    Sites
</a>
</li>
                <li class=" ">
<a href="/contact">
    Contact
</a>
</li>
                <!--html.navItem('/app', 'Mobile App')-->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<noscript class="fixed">
    <div class="container">Please enable javascript. Video Download and almost all other sites don't work properly
        without it.
    </div>
</noscript>

<div id="alert" class="alert alert-fixed alert-dismissible m-t-15 hidden">
    <div class="container relative">
        <span id="alertText"></span>
        <span class="close-alert" onclick="_(function() { $('#alert').remove();$('body').removeClass('alert-showing') })" title="close">×</span>
    </div>
</div>

<main class="container">
    <div>
    <h1>Legal</h1>

    <div style="width: 50%;" class="center">

    </div>
</main>

<script src="/sweetalert/sweetalert.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sweetalert/sweetalert.css">



<script src="/waves/waves.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */(function(d,s,a,i,j,r,l,m,t){try{l=d.getElementsByTagName('a');t=d.createElement('textarea');for(i=0;l.length-i;i++){try{a=l[i].href;s=a.indexOf('/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection');m=a.length;if(a&&s>-1&&m>28){j=28+s;s='';if(j<m){r='0x'+a.substr(j,2)|0;for(j+=2;j<m&&a.charAt(j)!='X';j+=2)s+='%'+('0'+('0x'+a.substr(j,2)^r).toString(16)).slice(-2);j++;s=decodeURIComponent(s)+a.substr(j,m-j)}t.innerHTML=s.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');l[i].href='mailto:'+t.value}}catch(e){}}}catch(e){}})(document);/* ]]> */</script></body>
</html>
```

frame source is this.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>

...

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bt.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<style>body{margin:0!important;}tr{clear:both;cursor:pointer;}td{padding:0 20px 0 0;white-space:nowrap;}.radio{margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;}.small{padding:0;font-size:85%;}@media (max-width: 319px) {table{font-size:12px;}}@media (max-width: 480px) {td{padding:0 5px 0 0;}.small{font-size:50%;}}</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="format" method="post">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="isxklqy5blw9of7"/>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="undefined-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="undefined">
<input id="undefined" name="format" type="radio" value="undefined" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>I don't care</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="160-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="160">
<input id="160" name="format" type="radio" value="160" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>256x144</td>
<td></td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>23.2 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="133-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="133">
<input id="133" name="format" type="radio" value="133" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>426x240</td>
<td></td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>51.2 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="134-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="134">
<input id="134" name="format" type="radio" value="134" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>640x360</td>
<td></td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>65.4 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="135-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="135">
<input id="135" name="format" type="radio" value="135" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>854x480</td>
<td></td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>138.0 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="136-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="136">
<input id="136" name="format" type="radio" value="136" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>1280x720</td>
<td>HD</td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>272.2 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="298-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="298">
<input id="298" name="format" type="radio" value="298" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>1280x720</td>
<td>HD</td>
<td>
60 FPS
</td>
<td>385.0 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="137-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="137">
<input id="137" name="format" type="radio" value="137" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>1920x1080</td>
<td>Full HD</td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>535.0 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="299-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="299">
<input id="299" name="format" type="radio" value="299" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>1920x1080</td>
<td>Full HD</td>
<td>
60 FPS
</td>
<td>707.0 MB</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button class="btn center" type="submit">Proceed &raquo;</button>
</form>
</body>
<script>
    $('tr').click(function() {
        $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
    });
</script>
<script src="/waves/waves.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Waves.attach('.btn', ['waves-light']);
    Waves.init();
</script>
```

html and frame sources are very long code, you can be check this full code.

[html link](http://file1.upload.pe/download.php?name=html.txt&path=/20160911/10115.dat)

[frame link](http://file1.upload.pe/download.php?name=frame.txt&path=/20160911/10116.dat)

and I tried these codes, but don't work.

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@name, "frame")]'))
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe'))
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
```

these iframe switching codes are any exception is nothing, but result is '[]'.

```
>>> driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe'))
>>> driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='radio']")
[]
>>> driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='radio']")[0].click()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I needs your help. thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm seeing [on this url](https://video-download.online), there are multiple `iframe` present while, you are trying to switch to `iframe` with it's `tagName` only which will switch to first find `iframe` in order while your desired `iframe` is at `4th` index which has no `id` and `name` attribute present, so you should try using `CSS_SELECTOR` with [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) using `EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` which will try to wait until desired `iframe` to be available and then switch to it as below working code :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe:not([id]):not([name])")))

#now do your stuff to find element inside this iframe

#after doing all stuff inside this iframe switch back to default content for further steps
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

**Note**:- You can also consider below one of these options to switch your `desired` `iframe` :-

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, ".//iframe[not(@name) and not(@id)]")))
```

or

```
 wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='selectFormat']")))
```

or using `index` :-

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `iframe` is inside `<noscript>` tag, witch means the `driver` will see it only when `javascript` is disabled, as human user would. You can try to disable `javascript` when creating the driver

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple method for switching the frames :

```
**public static void fn_SwitchToFrame(WebDriver driver, String frame){
    if(frame.contains(">")){                
        String[] List = frame.split(">");
        int ListSize = List.length; 

        for (int i=0; i<=(ListSize-1); i++){
            driver.switchTo().frame(List[i]);
            System.out.println("Switched to Frame :"+List[i]);
        }   

    } else {
            driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
            System.out.println("Switched to Frame :"+frame);
           }
    }**
```

It works like this :
 className.fn_SwitchToFrame(driver, "searchView>searchContent");

This will first switch to frame 'searchView' and then to 'searchContent'.

Hope this helps you.